# Extracting Multiple floating points from string in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am currently working through this book:
[Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H4D1W9E).

The question I am currently working on is:

> Let s be a string that contains a sequence of decimal numbers separated by commas, e.g., `s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'`. Write a program that prints the sum of the numbers in `s`.

I have figured out how to this for integers:

```
s = raw_input('Enter any positive integers: ')

total = 0

for c in s:

    c = int(c)

    total += c

print total
```

I tried several methods including try and except method, but I can figure out how to solve the

```
Valuerror:invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Update: I want to thank every one for their help. It is good to know that there are people who are willing to help the small joe.

Comment: Well, have you tried changing `int` to `float`?

Comment: Yes, I have but because there are multiple floats separated by commas, it can't convert it.

Comment: Next time remember to post accurate information - the error you present doesn't match the situation you're describing (the error is not about the comma you speak of now, but because of trying parse a float with `int()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a for loop.

```
# Save the string (e.g. '12.5,67.4,78.5')
number_string = raw_input("Enter any positive floats: ")

# Initialize a variable to hold the sum of the numbers
tot = 0

# Iterate over all numbers in the string. The string is splitted 
# at each comma, thus resulting in a list like `['12.5', '67.4', '78.5']`
for num in number_string.split(','):
    # But every element in the list is a string, so you need to 
    # convert them to floats, and add each of them to the total sum
    tot += float(num)

# Print the total sum
print tot
```

As others have pointed out, you can do this easier and by writing less code, but this may be a bit easier to understand. When you understand this, you may understand how the other solutions work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to ask I understand it correctly: are the parameters inside the split method are excluded? I appreciate your help, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3171116 If you want to read more about such methods, type `help(str)` in your Python interpreter, and all the string methods will be shown. You can also read about it in the online [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(map(float,raw_input("Enter any positive integers: ").split(',')))
```

This is sort of a quick and dirty one-liner as a quick hack. Here it is unrolled a little:

```
input_string = raw_input("Enter any positive integers: ")
#input_string is now whatever the user inputs

list_of_floats_as_strings = input_string.split(",")
#this splits the input up across commas and puts a list in
#list_of_floats_as_strings. They're still strings here, not floats yet,
#but we'll fix that in a moment

running_total = 0 #gotta start somewhere

for value in list_of_floats_as_strings:
    number = float(value) #turn it into a float
    running_total+=number #and add it to your running total

#after your for loop finishes, running_total will be the sum you're looking for
```

As for what EXACTLY the quick dirty one-liner does:

```
sum( #tells Python to add up everything inside the brackets
    map( #tells Python to run the designated function on everything in the
         #iterable (e.g. list or etc) that follows
        float, #is the float() function we used in the unrolled version
        raw_input("Enter any positive integers: ") #is your input
            .split(',') #splits your input into a list for use in map
        )
    )
```

Please never write code the way I just did. Keep those dirty one-liners as dirty one-liners, and explain them afterwards. I thought that format may be better for a one-shot explanation, but DEFINITELY it is far worse for documentation.

Comment: Well, at least it's short :)

Comment: Longer now -- figured I'd type the hack then explain the code :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` and `float`, e.g.

```
s = raw_input('Enter any floats: ')
print s

items = s.split(",")
print "items:",items

floats = map(float, items)
print "floats:",floats

total = sum(floats)
print "total:",total
```

The output would be

```
Enter any floats: 12.3,45.6,78.9
12.3,45.6,78.9
items: ['12.3', '45.6', '78.9']
floats: [12.3, 45.6, 78.9]
total: 136.8
```